# Sphinx code does not use language model

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am using Sphinx for speech recognition. I have provided path for both Grammar file and language model in my program. But my program only uses grammar file and does not recognize words that are in the language model. 
I have tried giving path in both of following ways to different lm files but none of them works:

```
private static final String LANGUAGE_MODEL ="resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.lm.bin";
```

and

```
private static final String LANGUAGE_MODEL ="file: dialog/weather.lm";
```

dialog is folder in my project folder, in which I have placed my grammar file as well. Grammar file is being used by my program but not language model.
Please help me. Thanks